# Firebase Auth Ui Google Sign In Code:10, message:10:

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase Auth Ui Google Sign In Code:10, message:10:

I use firebase auth-ui to sign in with google,

it toasted

> Code:10, message:10:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Code 10 often indicates a problem with your SHA1 fingerprint.  See Sam Stern's comment [at this post](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/360).

Answer (score 36):

Google this days are making simple things complicated.
The problem is the third key,

1- The debug key

2- The release key

3- Google Play App signing key

You need THREE keys to figure out ONE Google SignIn.

Does facebook also need three keys? 
Maybe one day google will need 30 keys.

Comment: Android Studio corrected the missing key for me when I connected it to my Firebase project. Took a couple of tries, but it got there.

Comment: Saved my life :*

Comment: You can obtain the third key by logging in to your Google Play Console > Release Management > App Signing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rosário Pereira Fernandes

Comment: A fourth key will be needed if you intend on using internal app sharing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763633/1702810

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes
Currently, the third key can be obtained from Google Play Console > Setup > App integrity

Answer (score 23):

To have a smooth sign in with Google across build variants (Debug, Release, and Store):

1. Go to Firebase admin console and open the project settings
2. Scroll down to "Your apps" section
3. Add **3 SHA-1 Values**. (the one from your debug key, the one from your release key and the one from Google play singing tab)

For debugging and release keys, you can use the keytool to generate the SHA-1 value as in the docs.

**EDIT**
To reach the "App Signing" in the new Google Play console:

- From Left side bar open Setup section
- App Integrity
- Then App Signing Key Certificate

For Google signing SHA-1 key, Go to Google play console, Open "Release Management" section and click on "App Signing" sidebar menu item. You will find the SHA-1 fingerprint value there under "App signing certificate"

Comment: this info seems to be lacking in any official google documentation. +1

Comment: You may have to search for 'App Signing' in the newer console, if you don't find "Release Management" section.

Answer (score 9):

These tips have worked for me :

**1 -** Verify your SHA-1 key is still corresponding between your app and firebase : you can generate this SHA key as @Yuliiia mentionned with the command line but you can also do it directly from you android studio project. Click on "Gradle" tab (on the right of the IDE) then drop-down android folder and double-click on "signingReport".

**2 -** Go to your firebase console, download a new version of the google-services.json file and replace the former one by it.

**3 -** Last trick : delete the account (e.g: testemail@gmail.com) you're trying to connect with from the firebase authentication console.

***Note 1:*** For each solution above I suggest to uninstall the app from your emulator or mobile.

***Note 2:*** Error code from firebase is not only code:10, it could throw code: 8, code: 16, etc.

Hope it helps !

Comment: this should be the answer. quick question: when I run signingReport how do I add the path to the keystore for the release variant cause currently for the release one it does not print the SHA

Comment: @user347187 you need to add it in the build.gradle -> signingConfigs. In signingConfigs, add a release type where you can define your keystore path. E.g : storeFile file('./keys/mykeystore.jks'). Specify the storePassword, the keyAlias and the keyPassword too. 
When it's done you just need to automize the signature. To do this, add this line 'signingConfig signingConfigs.release' in you release buildTypes. 
Launch the signingReport task again, it should work now.

Answer (score 8):

Have you added your **SHA certificate fingerprint** code to your Firebase project? If no, do it. [Official instruction to get SHA certificate fingerprint.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

To get the release certificate fingerprint (Linux/Mac OS):

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

To get the debug certificate fingerprint (Linux/Mac OS):

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

The keytool utility prompts you to enter a password for the keystore. The default password for the debug keystore is `android`. The keytool then prints the fingerprint to the terminal. For example:

```
Certificate fingerprint: SHA1: DA:39:A3:EE:5E:6B:4B:0D:82:59:BF:EF:09:68:90:70:AF:D5:07:01
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. I spent couple of hours to identify the SHA1 key.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, when I was using the downloaded version on google-services.json, but worked when used Tools->FireBase  and connected to database and di the sync.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue several times. In my last case it was that I was trying to build app without using signing configurations. So to let android studio know about my signing configuration I had to edit `ProjectRootFolder\app\build.gradle` to add following configuration.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("your path to keystore file")
            storePassword "keystorepass123"
            keyAlias "youralias"
            keyPassword "yourkeypass"
        }
    }
    ...
```

> **But it is not good for version control to hard code the values. Better to move variables to separate file. It is a common practice to move the values to gradle properties file. See below**

Even though the official documentation very good, as there are multiple processes on the workflow to achieve the end result, to make it more understandable I created a tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZoXmQ4nIbU&t=2066s) showing the complete process. Error code 10 and fix is at timestamp 24:43. See description to find out the timestamps of keystore generation,listing SHA1, signingconfigs setting and moving to gradle properties file. Hope this might help someone looking for the solution in future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the cause was that Google was handling my Signing Key, and I was trying to add the SHA1 certificate from my upload key.  Once I went to Google Play console to found the SHA1 certificate from the app signing key and uploaded that, I no longer received the error.

Answer (score 0):

look sometimes, the Google server ID and the client ID provided by Oauth has make confusion , let me clear all , replace the new clientID  with the old clientID in the google.json file , and don't edit anything more , and also put the server ID same , and then uninstall the app and rebuilt and then run the app ,,
Hopefully it will work ..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).